# compressing files in JAVA

Tags: java, file-comparison

My project has a requirement that I have to receive a file via a REST service(using jersey) and store it in the database.

The file size will be around 2-4MB.

The received file can be either zip or pdf format.
Before storing in database I would like to compress it.

I googled and found that there are many available classes like GZip, Zip, Deflater... I thought of using Deflater as it looked very simple.I have written the following code for zipping.

---

```
Deflater deflater = new Deflater();
deflater.setInput(data);
ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream(data.length);
deflater.finish();
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
while (!deflater.finished()) {
    int count = deflater.deflate(buffer);
    outputStream.write(buffer, 0, count);
}
outputStream.close();
byte[] output = outputStream.toByteArray();
byte[] output = outputStream.toByteArray();
```

---

Could any one please suggest for my use case If I use the above code is it fine or do I have to use some other classes to perform the same.

Thanks,
Kitty

Comment: so your code doesn't accomplish your goals? any issues?

Comment: If the file is already a zip file, it's unlikely to compress any further. Even if it *is* compressible, what format do you want to use to store it in the database? That should determine what code you write, not the other way round.

Comment: ZIP and PDF are already compressed.

Comment: This is not a code review site.

Answer (score 0):

ByteArrayOutputStream caches the compressed output in memory. you have to wrap it around a FileOutputStream to avoid any OOM issue while writing in case of big files.